# React-Router v6 not rendering in production

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I have run out of wisdom on this issue and hope for any ideas that could bring me on the right track.

I have implemented a React.js SPA that uses `react-router-dom` v6 to navigate through the app functions. The App works flawlessly on my localhost. When deployed to production the `<Route ... />` renders nothing.

I have checked that the deployment path is correct by rendering an `<h2>` element outside the `<Routes> ... </Routes>`.

### App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

const App = () => {
  const title = `${(process.env.REACT_APP_TITLE)}`;

  const TwentyfourStats = () => (<h2>Works</h2>);

  return (
    <Router>
      <div id="app" className="App">
        <h2>{title}</h2>
        <div>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<TwentyfourStats />} />
          </Routes>
        </div>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

I have tried setting `<Routes homebase={}>` while adjusting `"homepage": "..."` in package.json but it made no difference.

Many thanks

UPDATE: I have inlined the component `<TwentyfourStats />` in the example to remove any deps on folder structure. The result is the same.

UPDATE 2: The problem is solved, as pointed by @VitaliyRayets by using `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter` (see answer).

Comment: could you mention what is it that you see in production? Is it a white screen? and where have you deployed it? Could you also share your folder structure once?

Comment: Maybe in production your project not in main directory, for that you must change settings of your server. You can fast test it just use `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`

Comment: On the localhost I see "<h2>Works</h2>" rendered by `<TwentyfourStats />` while on the deployment server this is entirely missing.

Comment: Thank you @VitaliyRayets! The `HashRouter`works. Care to explain why?

Comment: I wrote belowe)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You use `BrowserRouter` that uses the HTML5 history API. Then you visit Home page. It doesn't work because in production the server looks for the file `/`, which literally doesn't exist. To fix this issue, the server needs to be configured such that requests to any route would be served the `index.html` file in your production build. If you use `express.js` it can be done as follows.

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

app.get('/*', function(req,res) {
        res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});
```

If you use `Nginx`. Config:

```
location / {
  try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

`Apache`:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.html$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

Instead of `mod_rewrite`, you could also use [FallbackResource](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html#fallbackresource).

If you haven't access to server you can use `HashRouter` that uses the hash portion of the URL (i.e. `window.location.hash`) to keep your UI in sync with the URL.

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had fixed that by adding an `.htaccess` file in the `public` directory that basically does that

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
</IfModule>```

Comment: Argh, can't format properly comments ... I guess one gets the point

Comment: Edited answer, added Apache config

Answer (score 1):

In my react case this error happened only when I navigate to links with more than one slash:
E.g
[www.abc.com/Users](http://www.abc.com/Users) works with apache rewriterule but [www.abc.com/Users/email@gmail.com](http://www.abc.com/Users/email@gmail.com) fails

My solution was to open index.html and make all links point back to main domain.
E.g Replace `<link rel="manifest" href="./manifest.json"/>`
with `<link rel="manifest" href="/manifest.json"/>`