# react router dom not showing content of Route

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to use `react-router-dom` for routing. yesterday my project still works normally, but after I deployed it with github pages, it suddenly breaks apart..

this is the content of `Tmp.js`

```
import React from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";

const Tmp = () => {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Button variant="primary">Button 1</Button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Tmp;
```

suddenly this code (App.js) doesn't show the components in the `<Tmp />`

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
return (
<Router>
  <div className="container hero is-fullheight">
    <Header />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Tmp />} />
    </Routes>
  </div>
</Router>
);
};
```

but this shows the content of `<Tmp />` as expected

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";

const App = () => {
return (
<Router>
  <div className="container hero is-fullheight">
    <Header />
    <Tmp />
  </div>
</Router>
);
};
```

any suggestions? what am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Check the console and see if you are getting any error there. Also which react-router-dom version you are using?

Comment: @ShubhamWaje I'm using react-router-dom 6.2.2. there's a warning that says `No routes matched location "/project1/"`. but yesterday it was still working normally. I didn't install a newer version of packages or anything though..

Comment: Are you exporting your app component because code seems okay and I also tried running the same code locally it ran correctly.

Comment: @ShubhamWaje yes I did deploy the project earlier. and after that, I wanted to continue working on it.. but when I run `npm start` it shows nothing. after I tried replacing the `<Route>` with `<Tmp />` it shows the content from `<Tmp />`

Comment: @SiddAjmera yes, I found the solution from the answers in that question. I already put the links on my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71005833/1235167). basically just need to use `HashRouter` instead of `BrowserRouter`. [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70261430/1235167) has more in-depth explanation for those who are interested..